# getElementById from iframe

Tags: javascript

could someone help me to understand why this errors

> document.getElementById("actContentToGet").contentWindow.document.body.getElementById
>   is not a function

```
function deleteElement(element){
        var elementID = $(element).attr("class");
        alert(elementID);
        document.getElementById('actContentToGet').contentWindow.document.body.getElementById(elementID).remove;
        alterContent();
        giveAllIDs();
        hoverLoad();
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
...contentWindow.document.body.getElementById(elementID)...
```

to this:

```
...contentWindow.document.getElementById(elementID)...
```

---

Edit from comments: It's not removing that element because that's not how you remove elements. Try this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('actContentToGet');
var frameDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var el = frameDoc.getElementById(elementID);
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

See the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `body.`-  getElementById() is a `document.` function.