# Cannot get element by id or className

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, getelementsbyclassname

I have an iframe that contains several div and other elements. I would like set focus to one of the textbox out of several textboxes.

I used:

```
    a = iFrameObj.contentWindow.document.getElementById('myTxtBox');

   But here, a is null;
```

I am able to get access to the textbox object using following code;

```
var myTextBox = iFrameObj.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('input')[52];
```

But I would like to use more generic method to obtain object rather than hardcoding the index.

Since this textbox has unique class name, I tried following code:

```
var myTextBox = iFrameObj.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('rgtxt')[0];
```

but i error:

```
"Object does not support this property or method"
```

HTML for my textbox is:

```
<input name="myTxtBox" type="text" class="rgtxt" id="myTxtBox" value="hello" style="display:block;color:Black;background-color:rgb(240, 241, 241);" readonly="readonly" />
```

Can somebody help what is the difference between these two methods in iFrame ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896360/getelementbyid-from-iframe

Comment: Can you show us the html of myTxtBox?

Comment: Which browser/version are you using to run your code?

Comment: I am using IE version 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $("#youriFrameID").contents().find("input.rgtxt").focus();
```

using jquery...

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$("input[id$='myTxtBox']").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByClassName method is only available on IE9+, so the error message is correct (although not that clear), there is no such method on IE8.

You can read more about it here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975198(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)