# Get element by Id from another page

Tags: javascript, replace

I need to change content of page1 if page2 contain specified element. This code works great if I get id from the same page

```
if (document.getElementById("page_element")) {
    var str = document.getElementById("destination").innerHTML;
    var n = str.replace("Login", "Logout");
    document.getElementById("destination").innerHTML = n;
}
```

But I need to check if element is present on page2 in order to change content of page1.

I must change this

```
  if (document.getElementById("page1_element"))
```

with correct path which is page2 (logged.html in my case). How can I do that ?

Comment: This is Javascript not Java :) Best to know what language you are writing in

Comment: Two pages in different tabs/windows or a 2nd page within a frame? Pages on the same domain?

Comment: You can use ajax to check for the element, if you have access to page2, using some framework would be helpful, like jQuery

Comment: I have one jquerry function that replace div id on page1 with content of need it div from page2. I use this jQuery(function($){
 $('#result').load('Page2.html #intro');  but its not in source code of page1 although I can see correct result in browser.

Comment: I have 2 separate pages. Page1 (mysite.com/page1.html) must look for div id in page2 (mysite.com/page2.html)

Comment: If you use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), you *can* simply use `getElementById` (as long as there are no duplicate ids) if you wait until the load has happened.

Answer (score 2):

Think this will work...

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId"),
    doc = getFrameDocument(iframe);

doc.getElementById("page2_element_id"); // [DOM Element]

function getFrameDocument(iframe){
    return iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
}
```

---

`return cond ? a : b` means:

```
if ( cond ) {
    return a;
}
else {
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstood. I have no iframe but 2 separate pages. Page1 (mysite.com/page1.html) must look for div id in page2 (mysite.com/page2.html) .

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. JavaScript runs in the browser, say, Chrome. Chrome can see the page that is currently loaded, but has no knowledge of the html files that are still on the server, until they are brought into the browser.
What you could do is have an iFrame containing logged.html that isn't visible (maybe 1x1 pixels, or a fixed position with a position off the page (left: 4000px). Then you can refer to the iFrame and get the element from there, this one explains how to reference an element in an iFrame: [getElementById from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896360/getelementbyid-from-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you... 
Don't be too hard on me. This is my first post :p

```
var element_change_content_page1 = "element_id_page1";
var page2_datatype = "html";
var filename_page2 = "logged.html";
var target_element_id_page2 = "element_id_page2";
var target_element_type_page2 = "div"

$.get( filename_page2 , function(response, status){
//You can also use jQuery " $.post() " Method instead of " $.get() "
//Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp
var data = $('<div>' + response + '</div>');
var target_element = data.find( target_element_type_page2 + '#'+ target_element_id_page2 )[0]; //There "might" be more div elements with the same id: specify index
if(typeof target_element !== 'undefined'){
    //Page2 contains specified element
    var container = document.getElementById( element_change_content_page1 );
    container.innerHTML = "Content is changed!!!";
} else {
    //Page2 DOES NOT contain specified element
}
}, page2_datatype);
```